# Image is not updating and not retrieving

Tags: php, html

I want to store an image in database.I tried by using inserting query but by updating (by using UPDATE query) is not working. And also retrieving query not working.I want to retrieve image at three places.

And here's my code... everything else is updated and retrieved successfully but it's not storing and retrieve image..please help me to solve the problem..
I'm using long blob data type to store image.

Update is done in PersonalDetails modal.Here is my modal and its php code.

`StudentProfile.php` (retrieve is need to do in both card and modal)

```html
<?php

// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Include Connection file
require_once 'Connection.php';

//define variables
include('Variables.php');

//define variables for errors
$first_name_err=$middle_name_err=$last_name_err=$admitted_date_err=$academic_year_err=$course_err=$dob_err=$nic_err=$gender_err=$nationality_err=$religion_err=$race_err="";


    //Create select query for retrieving data 
    $sql = "SELECT personal_details.*,contact_details.*,academic_details.*,extra_curricular_activities.* FROM personal_details JOIN contact_details ON personal_details.Student_ID = contact_details.Student_ID JOIN academic_details ON personal_details.Student_ID = academic_details.Student_ID JOIN extra_curricular_activities ON personal_details.Student_ID = extra_curricular_activities.Student_ID WHERE personal_details.Student_ID =  '{$_SESSION['student_id']}'";
   
   //Check query
    $result = $connection->query($sql);


    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            //Include Row File
            include('Row.php');
        }
    } else {
        echo "No results found";
    }

//Close connection
$connection->close();


?>

//card
//Image need to retrieve here
<div class="col-3">
               <?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($profile_picture).'" height="200" width="200" />';?>
              </div>
              <div class="col-9">
 
//modal

<!--Model body-->
            <form action="PersonalDetails.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="modal-body mx-3">

             <div class="row">

                    <div class="md-form col-6">
                        <?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($profile_picture).'" height="200" width="200" class="img-thumnail" />';?><br><br>
                        <div class="custom-file">
                            <input type="file" name="profile_picture" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01">
                            <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01"></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**PersonalDetails.php**

```html
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Include Connection file
require_once 'Connection.php';

//define variables
include('Variables.php');

//define variables for errors
$first_name_err=$middle_name_err=$last_name_err=$admitted_date_err=$academic_year_err=$course_err=$dob_err=$nic_err=$gender_err=$nationality_err=$religion_err=$race_err="";

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}


if(isset($_POST["save"])){

 // Processing form data when form is submitted
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

        // Validate input fields
        if(empty(trim($_POST['first_name'])) || empty(trim($_POST['middle_name']))  || empty(trim($_POST['last_name'])) || empty(trim($_POST['admitted_date'])) || empty(trim($_POST['academic_year'])) || empty(trim($_POST['course'])) || empty(trim($_POST['dob'])) || empty(trim($_POST['nic']))  || empty(trim($_POST['gender']))  || empty(trim($_POST['nationality'])) || empty(trim($_POST['religion'])) || empty(trim($_POST['race'])) ){

            $_SESSION['empty'] = "Mandatory fields are missing.Please fill the empty fields."; 
            header('location: StudentProfile.php');    
        } 

        $first_name = test_input($_POST['first_name']);
        $middle_name = test_input($_POST['middle_name']);
        $last_name = test_input($_POST['last_name']);

        // check if Name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$first_name) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$middle_name) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$last_name)) {

          $_SESSION['charachter']= "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
          header('location: StudentProfile.php');
        }
        
        // Check input errors before inserting in database
        if(empty($_SESSION['empty']) && empty($_SESSION['charachter']) ){

            // Prepare a select statement
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM personal_details WHERE Student_ID = '{$_SESSION['student_id']}'";
            
            $result = $connection->query($sql);
        
            // Check if student id exists, if yes then create update query
            if($result->num_rows > 0){ 

                $file = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["profile_picture"]["tmp_name"]));
                $sql="UPDATE personal_details 
                SET Profile_Picture='$file',
                    First_Name='$first_name',
                    Middle_Name='$middle_name',
                    Last_Name='$last_name',
                    Admitted_Date='$admitted_date',
                    Academic_Year='$academic_year',
                    Course='$course',
                    DOB='$dob',
                    NIC='$nic',
                    Gender='$gender',
                    Nationality='$nationality',
                    Religion='$religion',
                    Race='$race' 

                WHERE Student_ID='{$_SESSION['student_id']}'"; 

                if ($connection->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        $_SESSION['success']  = "Updated Successfully!!";
                    header('location: StudentProfile.php');
       } else {
        $_SESSION['error']  = "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connection->error;
       }

            } else{

                $file = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["profile_picture"]["tmp_name"]));
                $allowed = array("jpeg","jpg","png");
                // Create a insert query if student id doesn't exist
                $sql= "INSERT INTO personal_details(Student_ID,Profile_Picture,First_Name,Middle_Name,Last_Name,Admitted_Date,Academic_Year,Course,DOB,NIC,Gender,Nationality,Religion,Race)
        VALUES ('{$_SESSION['student_id']}','$file','$first_name','$middle_name','$last_name','$admitted_date','$academic_year','$course','$dob','$nic','$gender','$nationality','$religion','$race')"; 
        

       if ($connection->query($sql) === TRUE) {
           $_SESSION['success']  = "Submitted Successfully!!";
                    header('location: StudentProfile.php');
       } else {
           $_SESSION['error']  = "Error: " .$sql."<br>". $connection->error;
       }
            } 
        }

    }  



}

$connection->close();
?>
```

Comment: In `StudentProfile.php`, where are you actually populating the variable `$profile_picture`?

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. `stripslashes()` and `htmlspecialchars()` are not effective functions for preventing SQL injections.

Comment: What datatype is the column`Profile_Picture`? Also, why are you storing the files in your database instead of the file system?

Comment: I was used long blob as a data type

Comment: There are so many variables in my project so I create variables.php. $profile_picture variable in it.

Comment: here is it.$profile_picture = isset( $_POST['profile_picture'] )? $_POST['profile_picture']: false;

Comment: _"There are so many variables in my project"_ - Defining all variables in one global file sounds like a terrible idea. It's way better to define the variables you need when you need them in conjunction to where they are going to be used.  Anyway, if you set `$profile_picture` from the `$_POST`-array, then it will obviously be empty in `StudentProfile.php` since you'tr trying to get it from the _database_, not from posted data.